# How to connect my thermostat to Raspberry Pi 3 running AWS Greengrass Core?

Tags: aws-iot

Since thermostat is not an AWS IOT Device ,how can I communicate user preferred temperature from Raspberry PI to thermostat. We can only connect AWS IOT Device to a AWS GreenGrass Group . My Raspberry Pi is the AWS Greengrass core.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you have two choices:

1- You can control your thermostat directly through Raspberry pi by writing Lambda function(in python, java, etc). Then you can trigger your lambda by subscribing to specific topic(Fog computation). [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/access-local-resources.html) you can find more information about accessing your resources on Raspberry PI by lambda function(Also consider thermostat's interface).

2- If your application doesn't allow latency, then it is better to bring your logic to the edge. You can buy an edge(like ESP32, ESP8266,...) according to your needs and define it as Greengrass device and connect your thermostat to that.